# Check whether Service is stopped by stopservice instead of stopself

Tags: android, service

I want to implement different behavoiur if the Service is stopped by user interaction instead of the inner calculations.
Both of them call `onDestroy()` and no more.
I mean
`ctx.stopService(...);` inside somewhere in Activity
and `selfStop()` inside the service

I can't find the solution. Is it possible to detect only using internal Service methods?

Comment: You can bind activity with service by some manager, but this manager will still use method from service to check it. I did it this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511128/binding-few-activities-to-one-service-class-which-connected-treated-like-servi, but you propably mean without touching service at all?

Comment: @myway, yes just some simple flag

Comment: As a workaround you could use a flag, say `isStopSelf`, that you set to `true` before calling `stopSelf()` or, if not calling the method, right after the service is done with its job and about to be self stopped. Then check the flag in `onDestroy()`...